# How to see if div has a background image or not, after calling web service to set the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretty long title, sorry about that. I have the following `divs`:

```
<div class="my-div" style="background: url(path/to/some/webservice)"></div>
<div class="my-div" style="background: url(path/to/some/webservice)"></div>
<div class="my-div" style="background: url(path/to/some/webservice)"></div>
```

Sometimes the web service returns an image, and sometimes it doesn't, in which case the `background` just looks white (I'm sure it's just a style it inherits from `body` or whatever).

So my question is, how can I tell in my jquery wether this `div` has a `background` or not? I tried the following:

```
$('.my-div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).css('background') == 'none') {
        alert('no background set!');
    }
});
```

But that didn't work. I'm assuming it's because it thinks it has a background set because the divs styling is pointing to some URL. But even so, sometimes that URL doesn't return an image.

Comment: `'background-image == 'none` or ' '` Give a try

Comment: So, your background will always have this pattern - `background: url(...)` when there is one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the image, in that way you're able to tell if the URL returns a valid image or not:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onerror = function() {
  alert(this.src + " doesn't point to a valid image");
}

img.src = "path/to/some/webservice";
```

You can iterate your divs, loading images for each of them, but keep in mind that the loading is async, so depends by the real action you want to perform if the URL doesn't returns a valid image, you can't use `each` method.